Оф.сайт ffmpeg-webp
/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg-webp

Ранее использовал данный файл для работы с изображениями, на выходе которого получал файлы с расширением webp.
В данный момент на сервере нет данного файла и не помню от куда качал и что делал.
Быть может подскажите, оф.сайт откуда его можно скачать. Или в ffmpeg уже имеется библиотека для работы с форматами webp?

Стоит указать какую конкретно задачу вы решаете, какой исходник и во что он должен "превратиться". Ибо да, работа с webp есть в ffmpeg.

Спасибо, старая версия ffmpeg стояла и как то давно, что та наделал, что сейчас самому не разобраться....

Все работает без костылей)
